# Does using built in magento url rewrite hurt seo?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, seo, subdirectory

I'm building a dual language store front- French/English. Originally I was going to create a sub directory mydomainname.com/fr.

However now I'm considering using Magento's URL Rewrite Management. Since I only have English and French it would be easy to use this to rewrite my cms pages, and url rewrite on product/category pages is built in.

Does anyone see in disadvantage to doing this rather than creating a subdirectory? or any advantage for that matter?

Comment: SEO is (in this case) about "human" readable urls. Magento URL rewrite provides that, so there is really no difference between a subdirectory and the rewrite.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't think of any difference either, but nice to hear a second opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento supports this ability already through the concept of Store Views. It should be very simple to implement this and not require any URL rewrites. Basically you just need to create two Store Views, one called 'en' and one called 'fr' and then in your `index.php` detect which one to send the customer to, [using HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE as Magento recommends](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/how_to_automatically_redirect_to_a_store_view_based_on_the_browser_language), or custom logic like GeoIP, etc.

In order to create language-specific CMS pages and static blocks, you must create alternate versions that are tied to the appropriate Store Views. This means you will have two CMS pages with the same URL key, but each is tied to a different Store View. URL Rewrite Management would be a good way to create alternate URL keys that can load the CMS page based on a localized key.

Comment: I have my website setup as you described; however CMS pages share the same URL key. I want to use the redirects so that English customers see "mydomainname.com/about-us", and French customers see "mydomainname.com/a-propos-de-nous". Am I missing something? or is there a better way to do this rather than doing a URL rewrite?

Comment: @SeanM - I understand your problem better now, please see my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks. This is the method I was doing, but was looking for a second opinion to assure me I was doing it the correct way.